# MapToStoredProcedures not available

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I saw a few questions related to this on stack overflow but none of them helped. I am using VS 2019 community edition, I created an API project on .NetCore 2.1, and added the following nuget packages. (assuming all EF packages will be included by default)

> 1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
> 2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

After some time into the coding I needed to use MapToStoredProcedures in the OnModelCreating function..But its not available,

> entitytypebuilder doesnot contain a definition for maptostoredprocedures

after looking for a few solutions, i tried to

> install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

which did not work as there was a version conflict issue...

> NU1202: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1).

then i tried to install SDK and restart VS, then i again tried to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational nuget package but the same error was there.

Finally, I installed:

Microsoft.EntityFramework (6.3)
and an older version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (2.1.11)

which was successful but the MapToStoredProcedures function is still unavailable.

the using statement in the class also doesnt show Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational namespace...

I am very confused as this function used to be available in VS 2013 with EF 6. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i realize that EF 6 used to have the MapToStoredProcedures function and EF Core doesn't have it. (Not sure why they decided like that).

I changed my target framework to netcoreapp3.0 from netcoreapp2.1 and then i was able to install Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational packages.

Finally, I am calling my sp as follows:

```
var dbResults = _gecontext.ParameterDetails.FromSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.get_nextParamSummary @UserId={0}", userId).ToList();
```